# CircleInvalid and ClearCircle methods for a particular cell in excel vba 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I am using data validation in excel 2007. I am using this code to make invalid data marked with red circle.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rc As Integer

Range(Target.Address).Select

ActiveSheet.ClearCircles
ActiveSheet.CircleInvalid

If Not Range(Target.Address).Validation.Value Then
  rc = MsgBox("Data Validation errors exist! " & Range
  (Target.Address).Validation.ErrorMessage & " Please correct circled entries!", vbCritical, "Failure")
  Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

As you can see in the code when I put wrong data then first of that specific range is going to selected and then all invalid data is marked with red circle.
But I want that only that specific cell should be marked with red not all data .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code from an Excel MVP:

```
Dim TheCircledCell As Range

Sub CircleCells(CellToCircle As Range)
    If Not CellToCircle Is Nothing Then
        With CellToCircle
            If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
            Set TheCircledCell = CellToCircle
            .Validation.Delete
            .Validation.Add xlValidateTextLength, xlValidAlertInformation, xlEqual, 2147483647#
            .Validation.IgnoreBlank = False
            .Parent.CircleInvalid
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub ClearCircles()
If Not TheCircledCell Is Nothing Then
    With TheCircledCell
        .Validation.Delete
        .Parent.ClearCircles
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Note that you can't use the Excel standard Validation function on these cells.

[[Source and explanation of the code](http://www.sqldrill.com/excel/programming-vba-vb-c-etc/1003186-invalid-circles-can-i-force-their-display.html)]